# I want to find max number who contain series A100012345 in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table who contain id and type.

```
   id           type
A1000123451     a
B1000123450     b
B1000123451     b
B1000123452     b
B1000123453     b
A1000123452     a
A1000123453     a
```

I want to find max id whose type only b

means max id is `B1000123454`

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Your question title has sql server in it, but you tagged this with MySQL, what database are you using?  Also you say the result is `B1000123454` but this isn't in your sample data, can you please confirm?

Comment: You may not have control over the schema of the table, but if you do, I would recommend changing the data type of your `id` column. If you're already storing the type as a separate column, you shouldn't also be appending it to the `id` field. Make your id a plain `int` and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `id` FROM `myTable` WHERE `type` = 'b' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```